# How do I switch views from within a view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm making a WPF application making use of the MVVM light framework.

What I'm trying to do is have a login form in a view, when the user presses a button within that view it launches a LoginCommand for the attached ViewModel. From there I either want to launch a new window which holds the rest of the application, or simply switch views from the same window.

Currently I have it so that there is a view called MainView which has a content control inside bound to View1. However to switch to View2 I need to put the button for this on MainView, and not within View1 where it belongs.

Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually I do this one of two ways:

If the login window is a one-time thing required before starting the application, I will put it in the `OnStartup()` method of the `Application` object

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // Login
    var login = new LoginDialog();
    var loginVm = new LoginViewModel();

    login.DataContext = loginVm;
    login.ShowDialog();

    if (!login.DialogResult.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        // Error is handled in login class, not here
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    // If login is successful, show main application
    var app = new ShellView();
    var appModel = new ShellViewModel();

    app.DataContext = viewModel;
    app.Show();
}
```

The other way I usually do this is through a `ShellViewModel` or `ApplicationViewModel` which handles all my window management. This method uses `DataTemplates` to define each screen, and uses a `ContentControl` as a placeholder for the current screen in the `ShellView` or `ApplicationView`.

I usually combine this with an Event System of some kind, like Microsoft Prism's `EventAggregator`, so it can listen for messages of a specific type, such as `OpenWindow` or `CloseWindow` messages. If you're interested, I have a blog post about  [Communication between ViewModels](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/) that should give you a better idea of what an event system looks like.

For example, my `ShellViewModel` might start by displaying a `LoginViewModel` (a `DataTemplate` is used to tell WPF to draw the `LoginViewModel` with the `LoginView`), and it would subscribe to receive messages of type `SuccessfulLogin`. Once the `LoginViewModel` broadcasts a `SuccessfulLogin` message, the `ShellViewModel` will close the `LoginViewModel` and replace it with the `ApplicationViewModel`. You can see an example of this in my article on [Navigation with MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: This seems like a good way to achieve it. Is there not a problem putting this functionality in the code behind, as opposed to in a view model?

Comment: @benjgorman The MVVM design pattern is meant to keep the UI code and application code separate, and I consider the code behind the `Application` class as a magic area between the two since it needs to initialize both the UI and the application objects to start the application. Honestly, I rarely have more than 1 window in my application. I prefer to use `DataTemplates` and `ContentControls` for managing the current content. You can see an example of this [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: In your answer this part is causing he headaches.

   `if (!login.DialogResult.GetValueOrDefault())
   {
        // Error is handled in login class, not here
        Environment.Exit(0);
   }`

How do I bind this to a ICommand? I tried using a IPropertyChangedEvent but it fires before the login box appears.

Comment: @benjgorman The `LoginButton` which exists on the `LoginView` is bound to a command in the `LoginViewModel`. I'd have to look up exactly how I had it all hooked together, but if the login was successful, the `LoginView.DialogResult` got set to `true`. If not, it got set to `false`. Setting `this.DialogResult` in the `LoginView` caused the window to close automatically and return that `DialogResult` to whoever called `.ShowDialog()`

Comment: @Rachel I tired the above using your first example, think I'm missing a step in the app.xaml.cs, as the login dialog doesn't close after successful login. Any thoughts? I made a gist of the three related classes: gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/44c74ab0663abe3cacb4 I also made a question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257105/how-to-switch-data-context-on-successful-login

Answer (score 4):

Put your views inside `Page` elements, inside your `MainWindow` create a Frame and point it's source to your first page.

From then on you can use the frame's `NavigationService` to navigate your frame to another view, much like a web browser.