# How to handle enabled property of multiple tabs using Data Templates?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, boolean-logic, itemcontainerstyle

I have a Window with two tabs, that holds two different user controls. In order to enable/disable navigation to the second tab, I implement an `IsEnabled` property in both VM's from the `IPageViewModel` interface.

The IsEnabled boolean property is set to true when a `SelectedCustomer` is received in the `CustomerOrdersViewModel`, via Messenger service from `CustomerDetailsViewModel`.

So far this method works, as the second tab is enabled when I select a customer from the data grid in the first view. But the problem is when I try to select the first tab to go back to the initial view, it is *disabled*.

This is a screen cast of the specific navigation [issue](http://youtu.be/uS7AaXmFMLI?hd=1).

I'm not sure why as I thought when I set the IsEnabled property to true using the messenger, both tabs would be enabled.

Does anyone have any advice on the issue here?

In the `CustomerDetailsViewModel` I send the selectedCustomer via a messenger:

```
    private CustomerModel selectedCustomer;
    public CustomerModel SelectedCustomer
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedCustomer;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedCustomer = value;
            Messenger.Default.Send<CustomerModel>(selectedCustomer);
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
        }
    }
```

Then in the `CustomerDetailsViewModel` the IsEnabled property is set to true as the SelectedCustomer has been passed over:

```
    public CustomerOrdersViewModel()
    {


        Messenger.Default.Register<CustomerModel>(this, OnCustomerReceived);


    }


    public void OnCustomerReceived(CustomerModel customer)
    {
        SelectedCustomer = customer;
        IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

This is the ApplicationView xaml that holds both user controls, and the tabs generated for each:

```
<Window x:Class="MongoDBApp.Views.ApplicationView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MongoDBApp.ViewModels"
        Title="ApplicationView"
        Width="800"
        Height="500">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerDetailsViewModel}">
            <views:CustomerDetailsView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerOrdersViewModel}">
            <views:CustomerOrdersView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ApplicationViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>


    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"
                TabStripPlacement="Top">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why not just default the `IsEnabled` property of the `CustomerDetailsViewModel` to true? It's a tab that should always be enabled, so that would make the most sense to me.

Comment: Okay so the IsEnabled property is independent for each VM? Then that would make sense.

Comment: Yes, each IPageViewModel is a dataobject for each tab, so they can have separate `IsEnabled` values :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just default the `IsEnabled` property of the `CustomerDetailsViewModel` to true?

It's a tab that should always be enabled, so that would make the most sense to me.

Comment: I made a question on setting a View to load over the MainWindow, wouldyou have any advice on doing that in my current set up? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222224/how-to-set-user-control-as-start-up-view-in-application-view

Comment: @BrianJ Looks like the you got it sorted out since the question is deleted now. Here's a simplified version of the code I typically use for login though if you're wondering: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9489180/302677 :)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you assign new ViewModel, either CustomerDetails or *CustomerOrders*, to CurrentPageViewModel. Whenever you do so a new object of class is created with *IsEnabled* set to false by default. 
The work around is to create *IsEnabled* property in ViewModel associated with your View (ApplicationViewModel). Then in ItemContrainerStyle refer to it as follows:

```
 <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestoryType=Window}, Path=DataContext.IsEnabled}"/>
```

Neither *IsEnabled* nor *Messages* are required in TabControlPages' ViewModels since your *IsEnabled* property resides in main ViewModel and both TabPages refer to it.
**EDIT**
After a while I realized that it would be disable by default since IsDefault would equal false at very beginning. It is complicated because you do not explicitly create TabPage. I am attaching complete solution for this, take a look 
[here](http://www.filedropper.com/wpfapplication1).

Comment: Okay so if I move IsEnabled property to ApplicationViewModel, how do I set it to enabled or disabled based on a Customer being selected in CustomerDetails? I understand the rest not sure how the boolean value is being set.

Comment: When a selection occures send new Message and in ApplicationViewModel's constructor register listening fo that message. It is equivalent to what you did in registering/sending CustomerModel.

Comment: Okay but I also need to register listening in the CustomerDetailsVM, as the passed in SelectedCustomer is utilized for a query in that VM. Could I register in both the AppVM and the CustomerDetailsVM, just set the IsEnabled value in AppVM? Or is that a bad approach..

Comment: I updated my post, hopefully you will find it useful.

Comment: While that solution is good, I've accepted Rachel's answer as it's less complicated code wise. Thanks for the input though may come in handy in future dev.